# adapting a non-constexpr integral value to a non-type template parameter, and code bloat

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr, inlining, template-function

Consider a function object `F` taking a `constexpr size_t` argument `I`

```
struct F
{
    template <size_t I>
    constexpr size_t operator()(size <I>) const { return I; }
};
```

wrapped within a type `size <I>`, where (for brevity)

```
template <size_t N>
using size = std::integral_constant <size_t, N>;
```

Of course, we could pass `I` directly but I want to emphasize that it is constexpr by using it as a template argument. Function `F` is dummy here but in reality it could do a variety of useful stuff like retrieving information from the `I`th element of a tuple. `F` is assumed to have the same return type regardless of `I`. `I` could be of any integral type but is assumed non-negative.

**Problem**

Given a `constexpr size_t` value `I`, we can call `F` by

```
F()(size <I>());
```

Now, what if we want to call `F` with a non-constepr `size_t` value `i`? Consider the following:

```
constexpr size_t L = 10;
idx <F, L> f;
for (size_t i = 0; i < L; ++i)
    cout << f(i) << " ";
```

*(Why would I need this? To give some context, I am in fact trying to build a composite iterator into a container view that represents a sequence of "joined" (concatenated) heterogeneous containers. This would give the ability to say something like `join(a, b) = c;` where arrays `join(a, b)` and `c` are of equal length. However, `i` is iterator state so cannot be `constexpr`, yet sub-iterators are stored in a tuple and need to be accessed by a `constexpr` index. Individual `value_type`'s are roughly consistent so that the joined view can take on their  `common_type` type, but sub-containers and consequently sub-iterators are of different types.)*

**Solution**

Here, I have come up with struct `idx <F, L>`, which adapts function `F` for this purpose, assuming the input argument is less than `L`. This actually compiles fine giving output

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

and here is a [live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/71a0a2cbfa7e89aa).

`idx` works by recursively decomposing input `i` into a binary representation and reconstructing a constexpr counterpart `N`:

```
template <typename F, size_t L, size_t N = 0, bool = (N < L)>
struct idx
{
    template <size_t R = 1>
    inline constexpr decltype(F()(size <0>()))
    operator()(size_t I, size <R> = size <R>()) const
    {
        return I%2 ? idx <F, L, N+R>()(--I/2, size <2*R>()) :
               I   ? idx <F, L, N  >()(  I/2, size <2*R>()) :
               F()(size <N>());
    }
};
```

where `R` represents a power of `2` at the current iteration. To avoid infinite template instantiation, a specialization is given for `N >= L`, returning `F()(size <0>())` as a dummy value:

```
template <typename F, size_t L, size_t N>
struct idx <F, L, N, false>
{
    template <size_t R>
    inline constexpr decltype(F()(size <0>()))
    operator()(size_t I, size <R>) const { return F()(size <0>()); }
};
```

In fact, this method is a generalization of the more common idiom with a Boolean argument:

```
bool b = true;
b ? f <true>() : f <false>();
```

where `f` is a function taking a `bool` as a template argument. In this case it is evident that all two possible versions of `f` are instantiated.

**Question**

Although this works and its run-time complexity is presumably logarithmic in `i`, I am concerned with the compile-time implications, like:

- how many combinations of `idx` and its `template operator()` are instantiated for this to work at run time for any input `i` that is not known at compile time? (I understand "all possible" again, but how many?)
- is it really possible to inline `operator()`?
- is there any alternative strategy or variant that is "easier" to compile?
- should I forget about this idea as an instance of pure [code bloat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_bloat)?

**Notes**

Here are the compile times (in seconds) and executable sizes (in KB) I have measured for different values of `L`:

```
 L      Clang(s)    GCC(s)    Clang(KB)    GCC(KB)
 10       1.3       1.7          33         36
 20       2.1       3.0          48         65
 40       3.7       5.8          87        120
 80       7.0      11.2         160        222
160      13.9      23.4         306        430
320      28.1      47.8         578        850
640      56.5     103.0        1126       1753
```

So, although it appears roughly linear in `L`, it is quite long and frustratingly large.

Attempting to force `operator()` inline fails: probably ignored by Clang (executable even larger), while GCC reports `recursive inlining`.

Running `nm -C` on the executable e.g. for `L = 160`, shows `511/1253` different versions of `operator()` (with Clang/GCC). These are all for `N < L` so it appears the terminating specialization `N >= L` does get inlined.

**PS**. I would add tag `code-bloat` but the system won't let me.

Comment: Do you expect `L` to ever be greater than 5?

Comment: In my application (in the context I give), there's no reason why one wouldn't want to concatenate e.g. 105 arrays, especially if we consider multi-dimensional ones eventually...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I call this technique the magic switch.

The most efficient way I know of to do this is to build your own jump table.

```
// first, index list boilerplate.  Does log-depth creation as well
// needed for >1000 magic switches:
template<unsigned...Is> struct indexes {typedef indexes<Is...> type;};
template<class lhs, class rhs> struct concat_indexes;
template<unsigned...Is, unsigned...Ys> struct concat_indexes<indexes<Is...>, indexes<Ys...>>{
    typedef indexes<Is...,Ys...> type;
};
template<class lhs, class rhs>
using ConcatIndexes = typename concat_indexes<lhs, rhs>::type;

template<unsigned min, unsigned count> struct make_indexes:
    ConcatIndexes<
        typename make_indexes<min, count/2>::type,
        typename make_indexes<min+count/2, (count+1)/2>::type
    >
{};
template<unsigned min> struct make_indexes<min, 0>:
    indexes<>
{};
template<unsigned min> struct make_indexes<min, 1>:
    indexes<min>
{};
template<unsigned max, unsigned min=0>
using MakeIndexes = typename make_indexes<min, max-min>::type;

// This class exists simply because [](blah){code}... `...` expansion
// support is lacking in many compilers:
template< typename L, typename R, unsigned I >
struct helper_helper {
    static R func( L&& l ) { return std::forward<L>(l)(size<I>()); }
};
// the workhorse.  Creates an "manual" jump table, then invokes it:
template<typename L, unsigned... Is>
auto
dispatch_helper(indexes<Is...>, L&& l, unsigned i)
-> decltype( std::declval<L>()(size<0>()) )
{
  // R is return type:
  typedef decltype( std::declval<L>()(size<0>()) ) R;
  // F is the function pointer type for our jump table:
  typedef R(*F)(L&&);
  // the jump table:
  static const F table[] = {
    helper_helper<L, R, Is>::func...
  };
  // invoke at the jump spot:
  return table[i]( std::forward<L>(l) );
};
// create an index pack for each index, and invoke the helper to
// create the jump table:
template<unsigned Max, typename L>
auto
dispatch(L&& l, unsigned i)
-> decltype( std::declval<L>()(size<0>()) )
{
  return dispatch_helper( MakeIndexes<Max>(), std::forward<L>(l), i );
};
```

which requires some static setup, but is pretty fast when run.

An assert that `i` is in bounds may also be useful.

[live example](http://ideone.com/xQEL4N)

Comment: Thanks, this is indeed a very different alternative. This would be definitely faster at run time, at the cost of some storage space. GCC has indeed a problem with the line containing the lambda, I'd have to adjust. And Clang compiles in 4.7 seconds for `L=1<<10` (1024) but above that in crashes during compilation. Any idea? (in the approach of my own answer, I have managed even `L=1<<14` (16K) in 44 seconds).

Comment: @iavr rewritten.  Recursion depth reduced to reasonable and should compile faster.  `helper_helper` added for the fact that lambda`...` seems rarely supported.  An array of X function pointers with X functions backing them seems much less storage than X lg X actual functions.  :)

Comment: Thanks again, this tree-like log-depth implementation of `make_indexes` is something I had in mind doing at some point anyway (but I always left for later). GCC works now. For this last version, Clang/GCC give 13.7/40.9 seconds for `L=1<<14` so it beats my solution in compilation time :-) However, the binary is 1,9MB vs 839KB for my solution.

Comment: @iavr stripped symbols?  The arguments to one of my functions gets pretty ridiculous.  Making `dispatch_helper` `static` and avoiding embedding that symbol might help?  Also changing `make_indexes` to always use `typedef blah type` instead of sometimes inheritance might also reduce symbol bloat... not sure.

Comment: You're right, I forgot about that. With stripping, I get 746/694 KB with your/my solution.

Comment: Are there chances the lambdas get inlined? A while ago, I used a similar jump table generator technique (for a discriminated union, aka "variant"), which *effectively* created a class with a set of overloaded member functions for each type of the variant, and in this case, the compiler didn't inline.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper there are compilers that can `inline` a call over a function pointer -- I've seen gcc do it.  I don't know if it would be able to handle the above, and almost certainly only if the array index was known at compile time.

Comment: @Yakk I've got the very first version integrated into my "join-iterator" and it works, so thanks again! In my case, the array index depends on iterator state so is not known at compile time, and I don't expect the call to be inlined. But my solution was also not inlined (as recursive) plus it took logarithmic-time computation to get the index, so the lookup+call is still better I guess. The most annoying thing is that functions to be called are member functions so I had to adapt for extra arguments, pass `*this` everywhere as `t`, and use `t.f<I>()` instead of just `f<I>()`.

Answer (score 1):

If your solution have cap on maximum possible value (say 256) you can use macro magic and switch statement to simplify it:

```
#define POS(i) case (i): return F<(i)>(); break;
#define POS_4(i) POS(i + 0) POS(i + 1) POS(i + 2) POS(i + 3)
#define POS_16(i) POS_4(i + 0) POS_4(i + 4) POS_4(i + 8) POS_4(i + 12)

int func(int i)
{
    switch(i)
    {
        POS_16(0)
    }
}
```

Another possible solution is (with C++11) use variadic templates:

```
template<int I>
struct FF
{
    static int f() { return I; }
};


template<typename... I>
int func(int i)
{
    constexpr int (*Func[])() = { I::f... };
    return Func[i]();
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    func<FF<0>,FF<1>>(1);
}
```

Comment: I'd rather stay as far away as possible from the macro magic :-) The 2nd solution is interesting and looks similar (or the same) to @Yakk's solution, right?

Comment: @iavr yes, my `constexpr int (*Func[])() = { I::f... };` is them same trick that @Yakk use: `static const F table[] = { helper_helper<L, R, Is>::func... }`. Rest is noise.

Answer (score 0):

I'll take the obvious position here and ask if "I want to emphasize that it is `constexpr` by using it as a template argument" is worth this cost and if:

```
struct F
{
    constexpr size_t operator()(size_t i) const { return i; }
    template <size_t I>
    constexpr size_t operator()(size <I>) const { return (*this)(I); }
};
```

would not be a much simpler solution.

Comment: This is simple but not a solution. I still need to adapt a non-constexpr input to the constexpr call.

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly an answer and my question still stands, yet I have found a workaround that gives an impressive boost in compilation. It is a minor tweak of the solution given in the question, where parameter `R` is moved from `operator()` outside to structure `idx`, and the terminating condition now includes both `R` and `N`:

```
template <
    typename F, size_t L,
    size_t R = 1, size_t N = 0, bool = (R < 2 * L && N < L)
>
struct idx //...
```

The entire code is given in this new [live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d365a3de60c545f8).

This approach apparently cuts down a huge number of unnecessary specialization combinations for `R`. Compile times and executable sizes drop dramatically. For instance, I have been able to compile in 10.7/18.7 seconds with Clang/GCC for `L = 1<<12` (4096), yielding an executable of 220/239 KB. In this case, `nm -C` shows 546/250 versions of `operator()`.