# what to do when return type is determined in runtime in c++?

Tags: c++, return, armadillo

Here is the scenario: I have a column-majored matrix file in binary format to be loaded, the matrix may be short, int, double, etc.
Conceptually something like this needs to be done:

```
Mat<xxx> loadfile(std::string filename)
{
    std::string matType = gettype(filename);
    Mat<matType> mat;
    mat.load(filename);
    return mat;
}
```

But the problem is, since I don't know the return type, I cannot define the function in the first place.

Comment: Welcome to the difference between compile-time and run-time.

Comment: You need a type whose "size" is determined at runtime. See for example `std::vector`. You can build a matrix class around that.

Comment: But I am not worried about size here at all, I need to get the type.

Comment: The size has to be set at compile time.

Comment: I am by no means an expert in C++, but couldn't they use generics for this?

Comment: Could you elaborate a little bit?

Comment: @zoska Yes, I use c++11.

Comment: `std::string matType = gettype(filename);Mat<matType> mat;` - nothing like this is possible, all types must be known at compile time.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do this. In the simplest form, `loadfile` should be a template like that

```
template<typename T>
Mat<T> loadfile(std::string filename)
{
    Mat<T> mat;
    mat.load(filename);
    return mat;
}
```

so the user explicitly specifies the type by

```
Mat<int> mat = loadfile<int>("filename.mat");
```

Now if the file has embedded information about the type, what you can do at runtime is e.g. throw an exception if `T` is not consistent with the actual stored type.

If the number of possible types is limited, you could use a template function say `run<T>` to specify what you need to do with the data (the algorithm) and choose depending on the input, e.g.

```
is_type_real(filename) ? run<double>(filename) : run<int>(filename);
```

In this case, the compiler instantiates all possible (two here) algorithm versions (specializations) at compile-time, and the appropriate one is called at run-time.

This idea can be extended to a look-up table of pointers-to-function, which might look close to what you had in mind:

```
template<typename T>
void run(std::string filename)
{
   Mat<T> mat = loadfile<T>(filename); 
   // run algorithm for type T
}

using fun = void(*)(std::string);

fun lookup[4] = { run<int>, run<long>, run<float>, run<double> };

enum matrix_type { Int, Long, Float, Double };

matrix_type get_type(std::string filename)
{
   // read type from file, return it as a matrix_type
};

int main()
{
    std::string filename = "filename.mat";
    matrix_type type = get_type(filename);
    lookup[type](filename);
}
```

In passing from the run-time to the compile-time world, I think this is as close as you can get. This can be further organized, see e.g. [here](https://github.com/iavr/ivl2/blob/master/include/ivl/root/core/array/fun/meta.hpp) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21942081/adapting-a-non-constexpr-integral-value-to-a-non-type-template-parameter-and-co). But I just wanted to give an idea.

Comment: One could have a class with an interface that doesn't use templates but the class knows its element size. For example OpenCV's Matrix wrapper: `Mat A = Mat::zeros(3, 3, CV_32F);`

Comment: @GastónBengolea Ok yes for an existing library, but I wouldn't do this when designing a new program in C++.